# JUnit test предполагающий выбрасывание исключений

Tags: java, junit

Можно ли протестировать исключение в функции `eat` ?

```
import Enumeration.Taste;
import Object.Food;
import Object.Veget;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;

public class Cook extends Human {
    public Cook() {
        super();
    }

    public Cook (String name) {
        super (name);
    }

    public void cook (ArrayList<Food> foods, String name, Veget veget) {
        int rand = new Random().nextInt(4);
        Food f = new Food(name);
        switch (rand) {
            case 0: f.setTaste(Taste.SWEET); break;
            case 1: f.setTaste(Taste.SOUR); break;
            case 2: f.setTaste(Taste.SALTY); break;
            case 3: f.setTaste(Taste.BITTER); break;
        }
        f.setVeget(veget);
        foods.add (foods.size(), f);
    }
       public void eat(ArrayList<Food> foodList) {
        if (foodList == null||foodList.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("список блюд пуст, увы");
        }
        else {
                Food f = foodList.get(foodList.size() - 1);
                foodList.remove(foodList.size() - 1);
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                alert.setTitle("Вкуснота-то какая!");
                alert.setHeaderText(null);
                alert.setContentText("Кажется, вкус этого блюда: " + f.tasteToString().toLowerCase() + "\n" +
                        "Овощ: " + f.getVeget().vegetableToString().toLowerCase() + ", цвет блюда: " + f.getVeget().colorToString().toLowerCase() + "\n" +
                        "В следующий раз добавлю больше перца и лавровый листик");
                alert.showAndWait();
            }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для обычных тестовых методов Вы ставите аннотацию `@Test`, если открыть исходники, видно, что там есть параметр `expected`, как раз он и говорит `JUnit` что тест ждет исключение, например :

```
public class CookTest {

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testNullArg() throws Exception {
         new Cook().eat(null);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testEmptyList() throws Exception {
        new Cook().eat(new ArrayList());
    }

}
```

Такой тест выполнится успешно, только если в проверяемом коде будет выброшено исключение `IllegalArgumentException`

Как-то так

Comment: можешь пожалуйста уточнить, что прописывать в логике теста для проверни именно моего метода ?

Comment: @Daniil тут фрагмент кода, в таком виде его не протестировать, можно было бы проверить что делает метод handle, если вынести его в отдельный метод и тестировать его

Comment: я изменил код, теперь там не фрагмент кода, а функция, можешь показать логику проверки для этой функции

Comment: @Daniil я вижу, а метод может быть статический? если нет то нужно инициализировать весь класс, соответсвенно не плохо бы увидеть его сигнатуру

Comment: окей, я добавил весь класс)

Comment: @Daniil теперь тесты на `null` и пустой список тривиальны, я изменил ответ

Comment: Только не NPE,  a Illegal....

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець спасибо, я был невнимателен =)