# Как сделать проверку на то, что исключение действительно выбросится?

Tags: java, junit

на примере функции `water()`, в которой есть проверка на пустую строку и null

```
public class Farmer extends Human {

    private int planted;
    private int watered;
    private ArrayList<Veget> vegetable = new ArrayList<Veget>();

    public int getVegetSize() {
        return vegetable.size();
    }

    public int getPlanted() {
        return planted;
    }

    public int getWatered() {
        return watered;
    }

    public Farmer () {
        super();
        planted = 0;
        watered = 0;
    }

    public Farmer (String name) {
        super (name);
        planted = 0;
        watered = 0;
    }

    public void plant() {
        planted++;
    }

    public void water() {
        if (planted <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("с начало нужно посадить растение");
        }
        else {
            planted--;
            watered++;
        }
    }

    public void collect () {
        if (watered <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("растения необходимо поливать");
        }
        else{
            watered--;
            Veget veget = new Veget();
            veget.setRandVeget();
            veget.setName("Enums.Vegetable");
            vegetable.add(veget);
        }
    }
```

Правильно ли я написал тест или в логике теста нужно что-то дописать ?(под логикой, я понимаю - это вызвать water() без вызова plant() и должно быть исключение)

`@Test
    public void whenCheckWaterThrowException() throws Exception {
        assertThat(IllegalArgumentException.class, is(new Farmer().water));
    }`

Comment: Скажу немного по написанию метода - вызов исключения довольно таки ресурсоемок, поэтому оптимальнее - if (planted <= 0) {
            System.out.println("с начало нужно посадить растение"); return;  
        }     или смотря куда у вас идет сообщение о выводе об ошибке  . Могу не плохой материал по исключениям порекомендовать

Comment: я сначала так и писал, но есть задание использовать исключение. А дальше никуда оно не идёт, просто выбрасывает сообщение об ошибке

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [JUnit test предполагающий выбрасывание исключений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/964700/junit-test-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Comment: Нет, тест на выброс исключения в jjunit 4 делают с помощью аннотации @Test(expected=Illegal.....class). В теле нужно просто вызвать метод, который должен выбросить это исключение.

Comment: Вы же уже спрашивали и вам ответили. И еще раз ссылку дали выше на ответ на Ваш же вопрос!