# КАК создать JUnit test предполагающий выбрасывание исключений

Tags: java, junit

как протестировать исключение в функции `run` ?

```
 public void run() {
    ArrayBlockingQueue<String> bookQueue = library.getBookQueue(book);
    try {
        bookQueue.take();
        try {
            updateState(State.IN_PROGRESS);
            Thread.sleep(READ_TIME_MS);
            bookQueue.put(book);
            updateState(State.ENDED);
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            bookQueue.put(book);
        }
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    finally {
        updateState(State.ENDED);
    }

}
```

Comment: 4-й или 5-й JUnit?

Comment: вопрос задавался много раз, вот тут мой ответ на аналогичный вопрос с использованием junit4 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/964704/188366

Comment: Что этот код делает?

Answer (score 0):

[Источник.](http://barancev.github.io/junit-catch-throwable/#toc0)

Самый простой способ сообщить тестовому фреймворку о том, что ожидается исключение – указать дополнительный параметр `expected` в аннотации `@Test`:
`@Test(expected = InterruptedException.class)`.

У этого способа есть несколько недостатков.

Другой способ решает эти недостатки - `try-catch`. В тесте можно обернуть вызов метода `run` в `try-catch`:

```
@Test
...
try {
  run();
} catch(Exeption ex) {
  System.out.println(ex.printStackTrace());
}
...
```

---

Если вы используете JUnit 5, то эта версия предоставляет большие возможности для проверки исключений. Пример:

```
  @Test
  public void testRun() throws InterruptedException {
    //блок кода, в котором может вылететь исключение
    Throwable thrown = assertThrows(IOException.class, () -> {
      run()
    });
    //проверка, вылетело ли исключение. Если вылетело - то тест вернет положительный результат
    assertNotNull(thrown.getMessage());
  }
```