# Как можно проверить\протестировать обработку исключительных ситуаций? (JUnit)

Tags: java

```
 private String getTemplate(String templateName) {
try {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(
            getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("templates/" 
               + templateName).getFile()
    );
    StringBuilder templateString = new StringBuilder();

    char[] symbol = new char[256];
    int readBytes;
    while((readBytes = reader.read(symbol)) > 0)
        for (int i = 0; i < readBytes; i++)
            templateString.append(symbol[i]);

    return templateString.toString();
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "{'detail': 'internal server error: page not found'}";
}  catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "{'detail': 'internal server error: page cannot be read'}";
 }
}
```

Comment: Вы уже задавали подобный вопрос

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/964704/188366

Comment: Что тестировать расскажи по подробнее.

Comment: @RomanC если произойдет ошибка(ничего не было найдено, или же мы не можем по каким-то причинам это прочитать), возникнет исключительная ситуация. Как сделать тест, чтобы он проверял(подтверждал), что исключение действительно произойдёт, если появится та или иная ошибка ?

Comment: Если бы метод кидался исключениями (throws xxxException в сигнатуре), то в junit4 пишем @Test(expected=xxxExcetion.class) и вызываем этот метод с параметрами/условиями, при которых исключение должно выброситься. В jUnit5 немного по-другому. Но в вашем методе все ловится. Разве что можно ожидать исключения, которое выше по иерархии чем IOException или NPE, но я не вижу ничего подобного.

Comment: @kompil Если произойдёт ошибка, то ты ничего не тестируешь, потому что ошибки приводят к сбою программы и выходу из строя оборудования. Исключением являются те ошибки, которые генерируются в тесте, то тогда сразу станет понятно причину почему не было найдено или не может прочитать. Если исключение произойдёт, а оно произойдёт обязательно то надо его как-то перехватить, чтобы его не было, потому что неперехввчегные исключения обрабатываются внутри junit, что очень скверно сказывается на прохождение тестов и к останлву процесса построения.